# Android application for text and voice communication between devices on a same LAN

Tags: android, voice, livechat

I want to develop an android application with the feature that allows people on the LAN to text and mae voice call to communicate with each other. If there are tutorial regarding this topic, please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two sample projects you can refer.

1 ] [Audio Chat](https://github.com/DeanThomson/android-udp-audio-chat)

2 ] Text [Chat](https://github.com/hillfly/WifiChat)

Comment: Are there any tutorial regarding it?